# Add Data from two tables into a bridge table that has two foreign keys from same two tables in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, sql-server-2014

I have 2 tables and one bridge table that consist of foreign key of both tables. I am trying to insert data from both table into a bridge table. can anyone please help me out. Following is scenario.

- Tb1 `Product` (id (pk), name) --> column `Name` consists of 7 rows with different product name
- Tb2 `Vendor` (id (pk), name)--> column `Name` consist of 3 rows with different vendor name
- Tb3 `VendorProduct` (id, productid (fk), vendorid(fk), cost)

Also I would like to include the data for cost too. I have a feeling I have to use `FULL OUTER JOIN` to insert data for cost.

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: do you want to insert the cost data of all the products for each vendors into tb3?

Comment: Yes... I would like to insert cost of all products for each vendors

Comment: HINT:  INSERT statement

Comment: Hi I got this far:
INSERT INTO VendorProduct (Cost,Productid,VendorID)
SELECT
PRODUCT.ProductName
,Vendor.VendorName
,VendorProduct.Cost
FROM PRODUCT
join VendorProduct on PRODUCT.ProductID=VendorProduct.ProductID
join Vendor on Vendor.VendorID=VendorProduct.VendorID

Comment: where did you got the 'cost' of all this products for each vendor?

Comment: Hi ,I had to use INSERT statement to insert the cost for each product